# Parsing XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using rest-client to return XML from another website and trying to use Nokogiri to parse it. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ... 
<MXAUTOKESet>
  <AUTOKEY>
    <AUTOKEYID>27</AUTOKEYID> 
    <AUTOKEYNAME>WORKORDERNUM</AUTOKEYNAME> 
    <ORGID>xxxx</ORGID> 
    <PREFIX>12-</PREFIX> 
    <SEED>38979</SEED> 
    ...
```

I want to extract the "PREFIX" and "SEED" numbers.

My view code looks like this:

```
<% xml_data = RestClient.get "URL (sorry can't display it in this question)" %>
<%= xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xml_data)%>
```

The second line displays the returned XML on the page, so, I know the rest-client is working, but I don't know how to access the parsed XML.

---

UPDATE1:

I was able to get `creationDateTime` out of the XML header using the following.  But, I still can't get the SEED value:

```
<%= doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_data)%>    
<h4>Creation Date</h4>
<% root = doc.root %>
<%= root["creationDateTime"] %>
<h4>SEED</h4>
<%= seed = root.xpath("SEED").text %>
```

or

```
 <%= seed = doc.xpath("//SEED").inner_text %>
```

Comment: Please don't put all this logic in your view.

Comment: Mark - should it go in the controller or the model?  (Sorry - I'm new at this)

Comment: @Reddirt The controller. Extract the pieces you want from the XML in the controller, and then place them where you want to see them in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong in your code so here's how I'd do things:

Starting with this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MXAUTOKESet>
  <AUTOKEY>
    <AUTOKEYID>27</AUTOKEYID> 
    <AUTOKEYNAME>WORKORDERNUM</AUTOKEYNAME> 
    <ORGID>xxxx</ORGID> 
    <PREFIX>12-</PREFIX> 
    <SEED>38979</SEED> 
EOT

puts doc.to_xml
```

I get this output, showing that Nokogiri did a bit of fix-up to close the opened tags, ensuring a reasonably correct chunk of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MXAUTOKESet>
  <AUTOKEY>
    <AUTOKEYID>27</AUTOKEYID>
    <AUTOKEYNAME>WORKORDERNUM</AUTOKEYNAME>
    <ORGID>xxxx</ORGID>
    <PREFIX>12-</PREFIX>
    <SEED>38979</SEED>
</AUTOKEY></MXAUTOKESet>
```

`xpath` expects an XPath accessor, and returns a NodeSet, which is like an Array of Nodes:

```
doc.xpath("//SEED").class
=> Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.xpath("//SEED")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdf890e3208 name="SEED" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf890e3000 "38979">]>]
```

The problem is, [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath), and its [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) counterpart, will return every occurrence of their target they find in the document, which isn't what you want if there are two or more "SEED" tags. Instead, you want [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) or [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) or [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) which return the first occurrence found; I recommend using `at` (or `search`) and CSS for your first tests as it's easier to understand than XPath.

Converted to use `at` and CSS:

```
doc.at("SEED").class
=> Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at("SEED")
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdf890e3208 name="SEED" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdf890e3000 "38979">]>
```

Notice that `doc.at("SEED")` returned a "Nokogiri::XML::Element", which is how Nokogiri describes a node, instead of an NodeSet (AKA Array) from `xpath` (AKA `search`).

Getting at the text is simple once you have the node:

```
doc.at("SEED").text
=> "38979"
```

Here's how I'd grab both values and assign them to two variables, given the small XML snippet:

```
seed, prefix = %w[SEED PREFIX].map{ |t| doc.at(t).text }
=> ["38979", "12-"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last line of code, `puts doc.xpath("//SEED").inner_text`, should work. Does the real XML have any namespaces? If it does, try this instead: `puts doc.css("SEED").inner_text`

Comment: Using `xpath` and `css` will work on a simple XML file like this, but will fail by returning unintended results if there are multiple occurrences of the `<SEED>` tag.